# XML encoding safe?

Tags: xml

I am creating xml file with my own tags and given values and that in form of String and again I decode that in XML.
I have been said to
check that is code-decode XML is XML encoding safe.

Any idea how to check it? or any thing that make it sure that it is XML safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would want to write `</mytag>` as the content between `<mytag>` and `</mytag>`, you have to escape the less-than and greater-than characters, for example. There are several entities defined for escaping:

```
&   -> &amp;
<   -> &lt;
>   -> &gt;
"   -> &quot;
'   -> &apos;
```

What programming language/platform are you using? If you aren't writing the XML all by yourself, there should be ways that you don't have to worry about this!

Comment: I'm not a Java guy, but if you use an XML serialization mechanism, the framework/library should handle all encoding.

Answer (score 0):

An XML document that satisfies XML spec is said to be "well-formed," whereas a document that satisfies a schema (such as XHTML) is said to be valid. Since you're rolling your own XML-derived language, you likely want to check well-formedness. If you Google "well-formedness checker," you'd find them online. Any XML parser also could be used to check it.

The basic idea is like @Philipp is saying, you can't use certain characters between the tags (like `<`), all begin tags need to match up with end tags, and Unicode characters are properly encoded.